# iPhone setting title on toolbar?

Tags: iphone, toolbar, title

I have regular toolbar, with four buttons on it, and now i would like to set title to toolbar. Problem is, unlike navigation bar, toolbar doesn't have title property. Is there a way to make this?

Comment: What do you mean by adding a title to the toolbar? Do you mean adding a UILabel and removing all the buttons?

Comment: @MegaMan Can you share some code?

Answer (score 4):

To do so add a UIBarButtonItem, set text and make UIBarButtonItemStyle as UIBarButtonItemStylePlain. Or You can drag and drop a UILabel directly to toolbar

Comment: That does the trick (adding the button). Now if only i can disable that glowing effect when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `UILabel` either directly from IB or in code. Since `UIToolBar` is meant for containing controls it does not contains properties like title.